# Robot Framework and Selenium call java method

Tags: java, excel, selenium, robotframework

I designed to write a robot script to test the web page with Selenium.

After the execute the script, Selenium will generate the log.html and report.html which is provide some feedback about the test. However, i want to output like Excel format. I found the EXCEL library from apache with using Java.

How can i gathering the information and call the library to output the excel?

Comment: You need to write your own methods to get a excel report using Apache POI Jars.

Comment: I got your idea. Do you have experiences about create standalone automation robot? I want to create a robot for use multiple times, So that my groupmates can use without modify the robot code. Which format /waywould like to input the test data?

Answer (score 1):

For reading Excel, you can use like this-

```
Open Excel    {YourExcelFileName}.xls
${strColCount} =  Get Column Count  {YourExcelSheetName}
${strRowCount} =  Get Row Count {YourExcelSheetName}
:FOR    ${rowIndex}    IN RANGE    0    ${strRowCount}
    \   ${col1Val}  Read Cell Data By Coordinates      {YourExcelSheetName} 1   ${rowIndex}
    \   ${col2Val}  Read Cell Data By Coordinates      {YourExcelSheetName} 2   ${rowIndex}
    \   ${col3Val}  Read Cell Data By Coordinates   {YourExcelSheetName}    3   ${rowIndex}
```

And for writting Excel, youi can use keyword provided by Robot Framework "Put String To Cell"

Please find more details on ExcelLibrary provided by Robot Framework [here](http://navinet.github.io/robotframework-excellibrary/ExcelLibrary-KeywordDocumentation.html)

Below is code to read Excel using POI & Java. (Make sure you change the necessory things like file name, path, package name etc.)

---

```
package sbps;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

public class del
{

public static void main(String a[])
{
        String strConnString = null;
        Connection con1 = null;
        String strQuery = null;
        String strFilePath = Driver.APP_PATH;
        HSSFWorkbook xlWBook;
        HSSFSheet xlSheet;
        HSSFRow xlRow,xlHeaderRow;
        HSSFCell xlCell;
        String strLogicalPath="";
        String strColValue = "";
        Statement st1 = null;
        ResultSet rs1 = null;
        String strGroups = null;
        String strExeVal = null;
        int intNumberOfColumns;
        String runOnBrowser = "";
        String IEGroup = "", FFGroup = "", CHGroup = "";
        boolean IEFlag = false, FFFlag = false, CHFlag = false;

        try
        {
            FileInputStream xlFile = new FileInputStream(new File(strFilePath+"\\05_TestCases\\GroupControlFiles.xls"));
            xlWBook = new HSSFWorkbook(xlFile);
            xlSheet = xlWBook.getSheet("Groups");
            int rows = xlSheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
            int cols = xlSheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
            xlHeaderRow = xlSheet.getRow(0);
            Driver.APP_MAP = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
            boolean blnFound=false;
            try
            {
                for(int i=1; i<=rows; ++i)
                {
                    xlRow = xlSheet.getRow(i);

                        runOnBrowser = "";
                        strGroups = xlRow.getCell((short)0).getStringCellValue();
                        strExeVal = xlRow.getCell((short)1).getStringCellValue();
                        if (!strExeVal.equalsIgnoreCase("null")
                                && strExeVal.equalsIgnoreCase("YES")) {
                            IEGroup = IEGroup + strGroups + ",";
                            IEFlag = true;
                        }
                        strExeVal = xlRow.getCell((short)2).getStringCellValue();
                        if (!strExeVal.equalsIgnoreCase("null")
                                && strExeVal.equalsIgnoreCase("YES")) {
                            FFGroup = FFGroup + strGroups + ",";
                            FFFlag = true;
                        }
                        strExeVal = xlRow.getCell((short)3).getStringCellValue();
                        if (!strExeVal.equalsIgnoreCase("null")
                                && strExeVal.equalsIgnoreCase("YES")) {
                            CHGroup = CHGroup + strGroups + ",";
                            CHFlag = true;
                        }
    //              }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ee)
            {

            }
            if (CHFlag) {
                CHGroup = CHGroup.substring(0, CHGroup.length() - 1);
                Driver.APP_MAP.put("CH", CHGroup);
            }

            if (IEFlag) {
                IEGroup = IEGroup.substring(0, IEGroup.length() - 1);
                Driver.APP_MAP.put("IE", IEGroup);
            }

            if (FFFlag) {
                FFGroup = FFGroup.substring(0, FFGroup.length() - 1);
                Driver.APP_MAP.put("FF", FFGroup);
            }
            xlFile.close();

        }
        catch(Exception ee)
        {

        }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I need to use java as developing lang. I may use Excel library from apache and create some Keyword for insert,update,delete of Excel file.

Comment: I am little bit confused. So do you want to use Java with Robot Framework?

Comment: Anyways I have edited the code to use POI using Java to access Excel.